# Topological properties of $E\setminus\ker T$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a normed vector space and $T$ be a non-zero linear functional. I want to show that $E\setminus\ker T$ is dense in $E$ and that, if $T$ is not continuous then $E\setminus\ker T$ is connected.

For the first part, I tried to build a sequence $(x_n)\subset E\setminus\ker T$ that converges to an arbitrary $x\in E$. I tried to utilise the fact that $E=\operatorname{span}(v)\oplus\ker T$, if $v\in E\setminus\ker T$ to construct such sequence but without much sucess. (I can write $nx$ as $\lambda_n v+h_n$, where $h_n\in \ker T$. Then I wanted to show that the sequence $x_n:=x-h_n/n\in E\setminus\ker T$ converges to $x$.)

For the second part, I had the following strategy:
If $E\setminus\ker T$ is not connected, then there is a set $A\subset E\setminus\ker T$ which is both open and closed. I wanted to use this to prove that $T$ is continuous (at least at $0$). But without much sucess.

Comment: For the first part, to approximate $x\in E$, if $x\in E\setminus\ker T$ you are done.  Otherwise just take any $y\in E\setminus\ker T$ and look at $x+\frac{1}{n}y$.

Comment: For the second part, are you working in $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb C$, or is it not specified?  I feel like this only works for base field $\mathbb R$, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Aweygan It is $\mathbb{R}$ but I would like to know if this works in any field or not.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the first part! can't believe that I did not saw this!

Comment: A non-continuous functional has a dense kernel. A kernel of a functional $f$ can only be closed (iff $f$ is continuous ) or dense (iff it is not).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I know how to prove this. Does this help me here? I can't figure out how.